# Should I use Nginx or Route53 for redirection?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have problem that I don`t know how to fix. I want when someone go to webmail.mywebsite.com get redirect to gmail.com

So far I try to do it using Nginx using this code

`server { Server_name webmail.mywebsite.com return 301 https://www.gmail.com; }`

But nothing happens I get 'DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN' error on my browser.

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem.
Also I want to mention that I have SSL (let`s encrypt) install on my ec2

Comment: Route53 is a DNS service, you can't use DNS for redirection. Using NginX is fine. Does your domain actually resolve to the instance running NginX?

Comment: When I say Route53 I was thinking to put server IP adress on webmail.mywebsite.com and then maybe I will be able to redirect it via Nginx , I use same for my  admin.mywebsite.com but  there I have static page.

webmail.mywebsite.com I just want to use for redirection nothing more. @Exelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try following code block for NGINX? Looks like you are missing http/https port number.

Once configured please validate the NGINX syntax and restart NGINX server.

```
server {
# For HTTP
listen      80;
# For HTTPS
listen      443;
server_name webmail.mywebsite.com;
return      301 https://www.gmail.com;
}
```

Comment: Still doesnt work I get error when I try to access " webmail.mywebsite.com server IP address could not be found."

Comment: Can you please confirm if webmail.mywebsite.com A record is pointing to this server where you have configured? If you have configured *.mywebsite.com in Route53 pointing to your NGINX server then it's fine.